# Type requirement shadowing constructor declaration

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following [code example](https://godbolt.org/z/9ccd8b1T7) compiles with GCC 12.2/trunk and MSVC 19.33, in contrast to Clang 15. Why is the concept considered to be satisfied when there is no type `s` in struct `s`?

```
struct s {};

template<typename T>
concept c = requires {
    typename T::s;
};

static_assert(c<s>); // ok on GCC and MSVC
```

The rather peculiar error message produced by Clang:

```
<source>:8:1: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(c<s>);
^             ~~~~
<source>:8:15: note: because 's' does not satisfy 'c'
static_assert(c<s>);
              ^
<source>:5:17: note: because 'typename T::s' would be invalid: ISO C++ specifies
that qualified reference to 's' is a constructor name rather than a type in this
context, despite preceding 'typename' keyword
    typename T::s;
                ^
```

Comment: Didn't you plan to write `typename Ts::t`?

Comment: Yeah I did :P, Let me rephrase the question...

Comment: The other compilers (erroneously) find the [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name). This is a bug in the non-clang compilers.